# MFC Edit Control EN_KILLFOCUS issue

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and making MFC Dialog based application. I am running into strange issue with Kill Focus of Edit Control.

Please see below:

==========================================================================

In my application, I have two Edit Controls on Dialog Box.

```
1st Edit Control -> IDC_EDIT_QUALITY1
2nd Edit Control -> IDC_EDIT_QUALITY2
```

I have handled both's EN_KILLFOCUS event to validate the value.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestDlg, CDialog)
    ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(IDC_EDIT_QUALITY1, &CTestDlg::OnQuality1EditKillFocus)
    ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(IDC_EDIT_QUALITY2, &CTestDlg::OnQuality2EditKillFocus)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CTestDlg::OnQuality1EditKillFocus()
{
    ValidateQualityParams(IDC_EDIT_QUALITY1);
}

void CTestDlg::OnQuality2EditKillFocus()
{
    ValidateQualityParams(IDC_EDIT_QUALITY2);
}

#define MIN_QUALITY_VALUE     1     
#define MAX_QUALITY_VALUE   100

void CTestDlg::ValidateQualityParams(int qualityParamID)
{
    CString strQuality1;
    if (IDC_EDIT_QUALITY1 == qualityParamID)
    {
        m_ctrlQuality1.GetWindowText(strQuality1);
        if ((_ttoi(strQuality1) < MIN_QUALITY_VALUE) || (_ttoi(strQuality1) > MAX_QUALITY_VALUE))
        {
            CString strMessage;
            strMessage.Format(_T("Quality1 value must be between %d to %d."), MIN_QUALITY_VALUE, MAX_QUALITY_VALUE);
            **AfxMessageBox(strMessage);**
            m_ctrlQuality1.SetSel(0, -1);
            m_ctrlQuality1.SetFocus();
            return;
        }
    }

    CString strQuality2;
    if (IDC_EDIT_QUALITY2 == qualityParamID)
    {
        m_ctrlQuality2.GetWindowText(strQuality2);
        if ((_ttoi(strQuality2) < MIN_QUALITY_VALUE) || (_ttoi(strQuality2) > MAX_QUALITY_VALUE))
        {
            CString strMessage;
            strMessage.Format(_T("Quality2 value must be between %d to %d."), MIN_QUALITY_VALUE, MAX_QUALITY_VALUE);
            AfxMessageBox(strMessage);
            m_ctrlQuality2.SetSel(0, -1);
            m_ctrlQuality2.SetFocus();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the issue happens when, after changing the value in 1st Edit Control (IDC_EDIT_QUALITY1), say entering 0 in it and pressing TAB key, the flow goes as below:

- void CTestDlg::OnQuality1EditKillFocus() is called.
- It calls ValidateQualityParams(IDC_EDIT_QUALITY1)
- Inside ValidateQualityParams, it goes to if (IDC_EDIT_QUALITY1 == qualityParamID) condition.
- As the value I entered is less than MIN_QUALITY_VALUE, so it shows the Message by calling AfxMessageBox.
  **- Now, even from the callstack of AfxMessageBox, it hits void CTestDlg::OnQuality2EditKillFocus() internally.**

**Although callstack of OnQuality1EditKillFocus is NOT finished yet, OnQuality2EditKillFocus gets called from the callstack of AfxMessageBox.**

I don't understand the cause of this issue. Has anyone encountered such issue before?

In my resource.h, I have two distinct values for `IDC_EDIT_QUALITY1` and `IDC_EDIT_QUALITY2`

```
 #define IDC_EDIT_QUALITY1               1018
 #define IDC_EDIT_QUALITY2               1020
```

Please help on this issue.

Comment: Why not just use the standard validation properties provided with MFC? When you add your variable to the control you can tell it the valid ranges and then the system uses it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `EN_KILLFOCUS` notification for the `IDC_EDIT_QUALITY2` control you are receiving is caused not by the `m_ctrlQuality1.SetFocus()` call, but instead by the `AfxMessageBox()` call.

When you press the [Tab] key `IDC_EDIT_QUALITY1` loses the focus, and `IDC_EDIT_QUALITY2` gets the focus. Then you receive the `EN_KILLFOCUS` notification for `IDC_EDIT_QUALITY1`. You display the error-message, which causes the application to "yield" (start processing messages again), while the message-box is displayed. The `m_ctrlQuality1.SetFocus()` call won't take place before the `AfxMessageBox()` returns, ie before you close the message-box, and therefore the `EN_KILLFOCUS` notification for `IDC_EDIT_QUALITY2` can't be the result of that call. I guess it's the result of displaying the message-box (`IDC_EDIT_QUALITY2` has got the focus, but the message-box makes it lose it).

You may work around it by adding a memeber variable, as Staytuned123 suggested, but in a different setting: name it, say `m_bKillFocusProcessing`, and set it to `TRUE` while you are processing ANY `EN_KILLFOCUS` notification (AfxMessageBox() plus SetFocus()), and to `FALSE` when you are done processing it; if it's already `TRUE` exit without doing anything. That is, only one `EN_KILLFOCUS` notification may be processed at a time.

However, such a user-interface (displaying a message-box on exiting a field) is rather weird. And why reinvent the wheel and not instead use the DDX/DDV feature, which MFC already offers? You can define member variables associated with controls, and perform various checks, including range-check. Call `UpdateData(TRUE)` to perform the checks (for all controls on the dialog) and transfer the data to the member variables. Or you can put some error-displaying controls (usually in red color), activated when an error is found, like in .net or the web.

Comment: Hi Constantine Georgiou, Thank you Very much for such a detailed explanation. I have managed to get working solution with m_bKillFocusProcessing logic. I will consider trying DDX/DDV and UpdateData(TRUE), to see if it reduces condition checking overhead. Thanks again, indeed! Regards.

Answer (score 0):

When you pressed TAB key, IDC_EDIT_QUALITY2 got focus. But because value entered was out of bound, the program called `m_ctrlQuality1.SetFocus()`, which in turn caused `OnQuality2EditKillFocus()` to get called.
Add a member variable says m_bQuality1OutOfBound and set it to true right before calling `m_ctrlQuality1.SetFocus()`. In `OnQuality2EditKillFocus()`, when m_bQuality1OutOfBound is true, set it to false and don't call `ValidateQualityParams(IDC_EDIT_QUALITY2)`.

Comment: Hi Staytuned123,  

I have treid to incorporate m_bQuality1OutOfBound and made relevant changes. But, it still doesn't work.  

I am new to Stackoverflow and learning proper ways to share code and posts. Meanwhile, I have uploaded source code at: https://drive.google.com/open?id=17E1B6ZGeXttRKK-Fyf708cS37cfchx1I  

Could you please take a look at the Test.zip containing the soure code and suggest working solution.  

Regards,  
Hardik Shah

Comment: I tried out your programmer. Don't set m_bQuality1OutOfBound to false in OnQuality2EditKillFocus(). Everything else remains the same. That will fix your problems. Remember to apply the same changes to both IDC_EDIT_QUALITY1 and IDC_EDIT_QUALITY2.

Comment: Hi Staytuned123, trying with m_bQuality1OutOfBound approach, was still leaving out some cases, when Validation was fired only once and it wasn't fired again, evenif it was supposed to. I tried m_bKillFocusProcessing (as suggested by Constantine Georgiou above) and it is solving my problem. Thanks for all your effort to check my code and giving suggestions. Regards.